# GroupBy LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list of Questions that is grouped by Subject and Parent.

For example I would have

```
Subject 1
Parent 1
Question 1

Subject2
Parent2
Question2

Subject1
Parent2
Question3

Subject2
Parent2
Question4
```

Now I wish to display some sort of tree view, ie something like

```
Subject 1
    Parent 1
       Question 1
    Parent 2
       Question 2
       Question 3

Subject 2
    Parent 1
       Question 4
    Parent 2
       Question 5
       Question 6
```

How can I achieve that with GroupBy LINQ statement?

I have tried something which is not working yet

```
            var questionSubjectGrps = questionsBll.GetReportQuestions()
            .Where(x => x.VersionId == iLatestVersion)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.SubjectId)
            .GroupBy(subject => new { subject.ReportQuestionTitle, subject.ParentId });
```

Any help will be very much appreciated

Thanks

***********************************NEW CODE*********************************

```
            IEnumerable<ReportQuestion> questionSubjectGrps = questionsBll.GetReportQuestions().Where(x => x.VersionId == iLatestVersion);

        var tree = questionSubjectGrps.Select(questSubGrps => questSubGrps.SubjectId)
                  .Distinct()
                  .Select(q => new
                  {
                      Subject = q.SubjectId,
                      Parents = questionSubjectGrps
                                  .Where(q2 => q2.SubjectId == q.SubjectId)
                                  .Select(q2 => new
                                  {
                                      Parent = q2.ParentId,
                                      Question = questionSubjectGrps
                                          .Where(q3 => q3.SubjectId == q.SubjectId && q3.ParentId == q2.ParentId)
                                          .Select(q3 => q3.QuestionId)
                                  })

                  });
```

Comment: You you please format your question a bit better? I guess you lost some of the meaning through the editor!

Comment: So with your edit, does it now work?  What problems are you having with your new code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a couple of levels of `GroupBy` as follows.

This input matches the expected output you gave, rather than the input you gave.

```
var questions = new List<Question>
    {
        new Question { SubjectId = 1, ParentId = 1, QuestionId = 1 },
        new Question { SubjectId = 1, ParentId = 2, QuestionId = 3 },
        new Question { SubjectId = 2, ParentId = 2, QuestionId = 2 },
        new Question { SubjectId = 2, ParentId = 2, QuestionId = 3 },
        new Question { SubjectId = 2, ParentId = 1, QuestionId = 4 },
        new Question { SubjectId = 2, ParentId = 2, QuestionId = 5 },
        new Question { SubjectId = 2, ParentId = 2, QuestionId = 6 },
    };
```

The first `GroupBy` groups by the subject ID. The second `GroupBy` groups each subject group by parent ID.

```
var grouped = questions.GroupBy(
    q => q.SubjectId,
    (sid, qs) => new { SubjectId = sid, Groups = qs.GroupBy(q => q.ParentId) });
```

With two levels of `GroupBy` you need three `foreach` loops to get all the questions.

```
foreach (var subjectGroup in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subject {0}", subjectGroup.SubjectId);
    foreach (var parentGroup in subjectGroup.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tParent {0}", parentGroup.Key);
        foreach (var question in parentGroup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tQuestion {0}", question.QuestionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a GroupBy is actually what you want - I think you want a hierarchical structure. e.g:

```
  var questionSubjectGrps = questionsBll
            .GetReportQuestions()
            .Tolist();

  var tree = questionSubjectGrps.Select(questionSubjectGrps => q.SubjectId)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(q => new 
            {
                Subject = q.SubjectId,
                Parents = questionSubjectGrps
                            .Where(q2 => q2.SubjectId == q.SubjectId)
                            .Select(q2 => new 
                            {
                                Parent = q2.ParentId,
                                Question = questionSubjectGrps
                                    .Where(q3 => q3.SubjectId == q.SubjectId && q3.ParentId == q2.ParentId)
                                    .Select(q3 => q3.QuestionId)
                            })

            });
```

Comment: Hi Dave I took your suggestion, see edited question please.  However I am getting the following errors:- .Select(q => new is not being accepted, Subject = q.SubjectId, q.SubjectId does not exist, and same errors on the second Select in the loop

Comment: This is exactly what a `GroupBy` would do, just much less efficient.

Comment: @Rawling A GroupBy will only create a single dimension, wont it?

Comment: @Rawling can you give me an example of how you would go about to do it with a GroupBy?

Comment: `questions.GroupBy(q => q.SubjectId, (qid, qs) => qs.GroupBy(q => q.ParentId));` will do it with `GroupBy`s.

Comment: Thanks Rawling that works!  Would it be possible to explain the reasoning?  did not understand (qid, qs) => qs.GroupBy(q => q.ParentId)

Comment: @Rawling how can I loop through these to display on the front end (ASPX)?  foreach (ReportQuestion reportQuestion in reportQuestionsList) does not work

Comment: @Johann I've added an answer rather than keeping trying to solve this in comments :)

Comment: @Rawling This is why I love SO - There's always a better way to do things :D +1