# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, casting

I am grouping some data together, so that I can display it on the front page (ASPX).

I have the following code :-

```
IEnumerable<ReportQuestion> questionSubjectGrps =
    questionsBll.GetReportQuestions()
                .Where(x => x.VersionId == iLatestVersion);

reportQuestionsList =
    questionSubjectGrps.GroupBy(q => q.SubjectId,
                                (qid, qs) => qs.GroupBy(q => q.ParentId));

foreach (ReportQuestion reportQuestion in reportQuestionsList)
{
    ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay reportQuestionsGuiDisplay = 
        new ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay();

    reportQuestionsGuiDisplay.ParentQuestionTitle = 
        questionsBll.GetQuestionParents()
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                         x => x.QuestionParentId == reportQuestion.ParentId)
                    .QuestionParentTitle;

    reportQuestionsGuiDisplay.ReportId = reportQuestion.ReportId;

    reportQuestionsGuiDisplayList.Add(reportQuestionsGuiDisplay);
}
```

On the front end (ASPX), I have the following :

```
<% foreach (ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay report in reportQuestionsGuiDisplayList)
{%>
    <div class="hrLightBlue"></div>
    <div class="RPTContentTitle2">
      <%= report.SubjectTitle %>
    </div>
    <div class="hrLightBlue"></div>
<%} %>
```

However I am getting the following error :

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '``` System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable``3[SCPerformance.Shared.Models.ReportQuestion,System.Nullable``1[System.Int32],SCPerformance.Shared.Models.ReportQuestion] ```'
>    to type '`SCPerformance.Shared.Models.ReportQuestion`'.

Comment: At what line are you getting that error?

Comment: in foreach (ReportQuestion reportQuestion in reportQuestionsList) since reportQuestionsList is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<int?, ReportQuestion>>>

Comment: Why are you grouping in the first place? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Well I have a list of questions, and I want to group them first by Subject, and then by Parent.  Had another question here where I am detailing what I am trying to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735841/groupby-linq-statement

Comment: Sorry, no. The answer to your other question is right: You want a hierarchical data structure. I don't see that in your question, I just see a flat list.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to achieve, a hierarchical structure, and I was asking for help on why I cannot display something like that in my ASPX, since I was getting an error on the System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable which I have never used before.

Comment: Roughly speaking your front end code doesn't deal with nesting at all as your other question suggests you want. You are just taking a flat list and rendering it. You'll need to update your frontend code to loop through the grouped data taking out the group names and rendering them and then rendering the sublist of items.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
```

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx).

In your case, the result is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx)

In your foreach loop, do this:

```
foreach (var group in reportQuestionsList)
{
  foreach(ReportQuestion reportQuestion in group)
  {        
  }
}
```

But I'm confused as to what your code seems to achieve. It looks to me like you're just adding new  `ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay` objects to a flat list. Why do you need a nested structure in the first place? Can't you use a `OrderBy().ThenBy()`?
Also, retrieving the parent title is being done more often than is should.

I would suggest the following approach:

1. group `questionSubjectGrps` by parent ID.
2. for each group...
3. ... retrieve the parent title
4. ... add a new ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay to the `reportQuestionsGuiDisplayList`
5. order `reportQuestionsGuiDisplayList` by subject ID, then by parent ID.

(this will probably involve adding ParentID and SubjectID properties to `ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay`. Or perhaps a ReportQuestion, if that is appropriate)

Or in code:

```
var questionGroups =
    questionsBll.GetReportQuestions()
                .Where(x => x.VersionId == iLatestVersion)
                .GroupBy(q => q.ParentId);

var displayList = new List<ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay>();

foreach (var questionGroup in questionGroups)
{
    var title = questionsBll.GetQuestionParents()
                    .First(x => x.QuestionParentId == group.Key)
                    .QuestionParentTitle;

    foreach (var question in questionGroup)
    {
        var reportQuestionsGuiDisplay = 
            new ReportQuestionsGuiDisplay() 
            { 
               ParentQuestionTitle = title,
               ReportID = question.ReportID,
               SubjectID = question.SubjectID,
               ParentID = question.ParentID 
            };

        displayList.Add(reportQuestionsGuiDisplay);
    }
}

reportQuestionsGuiDisplayList = displayList.OrderBy(q => q.SubjectID)
                                           .ThenBy(q => q.ParentID);
```

Comment: Thanks Daan, this is very close to what I want to achieve.  Basically I need my list to be groupedby Subject first, then ParentId, and then get this List, and in the front end loop through it to display my questions first grouped by Subject and then grouped by Parent.